# How to count the recurrence of a word based upon it being a member of another list

Tags: python, list, compare

I'm trying the count the recurrence of certain words in a list `childList` based upon their membership in another list `motherList`

### For Example

`childList= ['hello', 'i', 'love', 'cake', 'yay!'`

`motherList= ['yay!', 'love']`

My question is 2-fold:

**what data structure would allow me to keep a record of each words occurance?**

**How would I then count their recurrences?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension and `list.count` to create your counter dictionary  :

```
>>> {i:words.count(i) for i in positiveWords}
{'yay!': 1, 'love': 1}
```